# Is there the way to tranfer event trigger from one Zabbix server to another Zabbix server?

Tags: server, cloud, zabbix

I have 2 Zabbix server. Each one serve a separate Data center. Now i want to collect event from 1 Zabbix server and push it to another. Until that I can use one monitor to observe many data center.

Hmm, Many thanks and welcome always any idea :<3

Comment: Why don't you just use Zabbix Proxy to collect data from different data centers?

Comment: Hi Iron Bishop,